# powershell display variable global?

Tags: powershell, foreach, sql-server-2012, global-variables

Why does this display nothing?

```
$result = foreach($db in sqlps ls SQLSERVER:\\SQL\\MYSERVER\\Databases) {
    foreach($group in $db.FileGroups) {
        write @{Database=$group}
    }
}
$result | % { $_.Database }
```

But this one works fine?

```
$result = foreach($db in sqlps ls SQLSERVER:\\SQL\\MYSERVER\\Databases) {
    write @{Database=$db}
}
$result | % { $_.Database}
```

How do I fix it?

## Edit:

It works ,but **how display the result like 'NameMyBase' = 'Status'**

> Blockquote
>   Get-ChildItem  SQLSERVER:\SQL\BACKUP1\ARCSERVE_DB\Databases | select FileGroups
>   Blockquote

I have just the column **empty**

Nevertheless "select -Expand FileGroups" doesn't work : Property "FileGroups-Expand" cannot be found.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, you 're right for the forgotten word : INSTANCE 
I have powershell version 3 and if i add Add-PSSnapin SqlServerProviderSnapin100, i get

> Blockquote

Add-PSSnapin : No snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell version 3.

> Blockquote

Comment: $result = foreach($db in sqlps ls Get-ChildItem  SQLSERVER:\\SQL\\TOTO\\Databases) { writ+ ..  CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException

Comment: Which version of SQL Server is installed on the host where you're running the script? What is the output of `Get-PSSnapin -registered`? And you need to remove the `sqlps ls`. You're not supposed to use `sqlps` there.

Comment: i have to use sqlps because it 's sql server 2012           Get-PSSnapin : The term 'Get-PSSnapin' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, o
At line:1 char:13
+ Get-PSSnapin <<<<  -registered
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-PSSnapin:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: With SQL Server 2012 try `Import-Module 'sqlps' -DisableNameChecking` ([see here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231286.aspx)). I added a respective tag to your question.

Comment: If `select -Expand FileGroups` throws an error you need to check if the output actually has a `FileGroups` property. Replace `| select -Expand FileGroups` with `| Format-List *`. That prints all properties and their values in list format.

Answer (score 2):

The default output format of `sqlps` is text, so your command `sqlps ls SQLSERVER:\\SQL\\MYSERVER\\Databases` is generating a bunch of strings (which don't have a `FileGroups` property) rather than the objects you seem to expect.

Also, I think your path is missing the instance. `\SQL\HOSTNAME\Databases` should raise an error (or at least it did for me). I had to use `\SQL\HOSTNAME\INSTANCE\Databases`.

Try something like this:

```
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerProviderSnapin100

Get-ChildItem SQLSERVER:\SQL\MYSERVER\INSTANCE\Databases |
    select -Expand FileGroups
```

The snap-in adds the `SQLSERVER:` provider, so you can use `Get-ChildItem` for accessing the child objects.

**Edit:** With SQL Server 2012 there should be a [loadable `sqlps` module](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231286.aspx):

```
Import-Module 'sqlps' -DisableNameChecking
```

I don't have access to an SQL Server 2012, though, so I can't verify that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much it 's OK for acceess object even if i hva sql 2012
i much use command like '

> Blockquote
>    sqlps ls SQLSERVER:\SQL\BACKUP1\ARCSERVE_DB\Databases; foreach ($Item in Get-ChildItem) { write @{$Item.Name=$Item.Status}}
>   Blockquote

This comman list what contains the root and not what contains the Databases 
I would like to do a Set-Location but the cursor don't move it display always the same thing, the root

> Blockquote
>    sqlps Set-Location SQLSERVER:\SQL\BACKUP1\ARCSERVE_DB\Databases; foreach ($Item in Get-ChildItem) { write @{$Item.Name=$Item.Status}}
>   Blockquote

The Set-Location works fine if i use the command not in my program c++ but with shell prompt. How can i use Set- Location in **ONE LIN**E with sqlps?